# How to Delay NofificationManager to trigger every 15 mins in android

Tags: android, wifimanager, notificationmanager

Am currently building an android application using BroadcastReceiver, it's a WifiDetection application that scans for a unique SSID, My notification works fine but always triggers every 1second (Which is annoying), I want it to be delayed for 15 minutes or 30 minutes. here are some of my codes.
I have used Thread.sleep() and handlers but it slows and crashes my application

```
public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private void receiveNotification(Context context, String ssid) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1001, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.wifilogosmaller);
    builder.setContentTitle("Free " + ssid + ", Click for more info");
    builder.setContentText("Wifi.com.ng services avaliable ");
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.wifilogosmaller));
    builder.setSubText("Tap to view");
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
    Notification notification = builder.build();
    NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mgr.notify(1001, notification);
```

}

```
@Override
public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent)
    {
     //Checked for the particular SSID am looking for
    if(condition is met){
    receiveNotification(Context context, "My unique SSID") 
    }       
  }
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent)
    {
  SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(); 

 if(!prefs.getBoolean("isNotificationFired", false))
   {
    receiveNotification(Context context, "My unique SSID") 
    prefs.edit().putBoolean("isNotificationFired", true).commit();
    //start service here
    Intent intent=new Intent(context, MyService.class);
    context.startService(intent);     
  }
  }

private void receiveNotification(Context context, String ssid) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1001, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.wifilogosmaller);
    builder.setContentTitle("Free " + ssid + ", Click for more info");
    builder.setContentText("Wifi.com.ng services avaliable ");
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.wifilogosmaller));
    builder.setSubText("Tap to view");
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
    Notification notification = builder.build();
    NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager) 
    context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mgr.notify(1001, notification);
}
```

Make your own service which will change the status of boolean value "isNotificationFired" saved in pref after 15 min...

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private final LocalBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    protected Handler handler;

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public MyServicegetService() {
            return MyService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 15*60*1000);//**15 min(time in millisecond)**
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

         SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(); 
         prefs.edit().putBoolean("isNotificationFired", true).commit();

        }
    };
```

Comment: I tried your code,but it didnt work as expected, it only paused the time for start execution, when the task starts, it continues to run every 1sec.

Comment: Please use the same code but use IntentService instead of extending Service...and write 
 ssid= intent.getStringExtra("ssid");
        handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 15*60*1000);//**15 min(time in millisecond)**
        return Service.START_STICKY;
inside onHandleIntent method

Comment: onHandleIntent returns void rather than int, so START_STICKY throws an error. using your code without a return type makes the app to crash.

Comment: @CWilliams bro i have edit my solution now implement and let me know if any problem.

Comment: your logic really helped me in getting the solution, what I did was to create an array of minutes [0, 15, 30, 45,], then I retrieve the current time from my receiver class, whenever the user system time matches the min array, i then check for the system seconds, once the system is [x==10 && x<11] where x is seconds, start the service, from the service class, i then trigger the notification.

Comment: I am new to StackOverflow, my reputation is lower than 15, so am not allowed to vote publicly. but thanks very much as you have saved me my Job.

Comment: @CWilliams ur welcome bro, where r u working right now?

Comment: @Mod Saquib, I recently joined an IT department in Shell Nigeria, so that was my first project

Comment: @CWilliams ok pls contact if any problem bro., is it IT comapony or government oraganization?